# Unable to use ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

My preview is giving an error while I am trying to use ListView.

look carefully below the android device. the error.

[image: this is the screenshot of my problem]
it also says "Failed to find style 'listViewStyle' in current theme"

I have not yet added the adapter to this list view. If that is the problem, then tell me.

my java code for this activity

```
package com.justforyou.bestnarutosongs;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SongsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;
private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange){
        if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK || focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT){
            mediaplayer.pause();
            mediaplayer.seekTo(0);
        }
        else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN){
            mediaplayer.start();
        }
        else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS){
            if(mediaplayer != null)
            {
                mediaplayer.release();
                mediaplayer = null;
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_songs_list);
}
}
```

here is my style.xml

```
<!-- Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
</style>

<!-- Style for a category of vocabulary words -->
<style name="CategoryStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/list_item_height</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceMedium</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the drop down menu from 24 to 23?

Answer (score 2):

You should put your ListView in a specific layout like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc...

Like this example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the API level from right top corner, Currently it is 24. After changing run the application. I hope it will work.